# Is password_verify binary data safe?

Tags: php, passwords

Here is the code, results looks very interesting:

Simple version:

```
$str1 = hex2bin('71f6f2170242774f6252191ff08b6d50e8762d49b46fe105d7bed9a563156971806f6f34dccdff148366a79830c4529a5052a7db6c7034577e5fe4912a7960e95b4f40c20015');
$str2 = hex2bin('71f6f2170242774f6252191ff08b6d50e8762d49b46fe105d7bed9a563156971806f6f34dccdff148366a79830c4529a5052a7db6c7034577e5fe4912a7960e95b4f40c2');
$hash = password_hash($str1, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

var_dump(password_verify($str2, $hash)); // export: bool(true)
```

More complex version:

```
$pass = 0;
$fail = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
    $password_org = random_bytes(70);

    $hash = password_hash($password_org, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $password = substr($password_org, 0, 68);

    if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
        var_dump([bin2hex($password_org), bin2hex($password)]);
        $pass++;
    } else {
        $fail++;
    }
}
echo "Pass: $pass\nFail: $fail\n";
```

The result always shows some failed, some passed.
I cannot find the answer from http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php , anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 1):

It's because random_bytes or hex2bin generate unexpected break characters (\0), and when you pass it to password_hash the real password is truncated, and for this when you use substr sometimes the real password (truncated by break character) is more short.

If you wrap with the bin2hex function `$password_org = bin2hex(random_bytes(70));` you got always fails.

Comment: I had same thought, which proves password_verify is not binary safe? I also tried to remove all \s, still not working as expected. Example:   string(140) "ab662254b9595277e859d261583d9cc2bd672e612490c9ef4aa8f900676446592f1bb9ee97cd5e2ab573ebfdaaf8f647bd73b0c4299c0863ff84f9f9e888529e6183b83740cf"
  string(136) "ab662254b9595277e859d261583d9cc2bd672e612490c9ef4aa8f900676446592f1bb9ee97cd5e2ab573ebfdaaf8f647bd73b0c4299c0863ff84f9f9e888529e6183b837"

Answer (score 0):

With the help from @Clemen, I found the answer, password_verify cannot handle \00 ~ \20 properly. To fix it (I do not know if it is ideal, may be it is a bad practice):

Change from:

```
$password_org = random_bytes(70);
```

To

```
$password_org = preg_replace_callback('/[\x00-\x20]/', function($str) {
    return hex2bin(dechex(random_int(33, 255)));
}, random_bytes(70));
```

Comment: User passwords never contain such characters, this is a hypothetical case. The only situation you can find `\0` characters in a user password is, when somebody tries to hack the system. This does not make the stored passwords less safe though, because a real user does not make his passwords weak on purpose.